# Quando sobe uma DLL na pasta "bin" todos usuários perdem sessão

Tags: c#, asp.net

Toda vez que subo uma DLL do meu site, derrubo todos usuários que precisam de `session` para permanecer logado na administração.

Estava utilizando a compilação que transforma tudo em .dll e .compiled
porém ao compilar para .aspx + .dll também acontece a mesma coisa.

ex:

Subo a DLL responsável pelas entidades cai todo mundo.

Isso é normal no ASP.NET ?

Devo mudar o sistema de segurança na administração para não usar Session?

Estou compilando errado ?

(Precompile during publishing > Allow precompiled site to be updatable)

No ASP Classic eu poderia mudar vários arquivos sem derrubar a `session`! essa é uma limitação do ASP.Net ou é eu que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Isso é by-design cara... se você quer que as sessões sejam persistentes vai ter de usar um provedor de sessão baseado em banco de dados ou então baseado em servidor de sessão externo.

Comment: session via banco de dados, esta fora de questão...não compensa..o problema é que tenho mais de 200 DLL e se modifico apenas 1 cai todo mundo.

Comment: Poderia então usar um servidor de sessão externo, out-of-process. A sessão no seu caso some pois ela é in-process, sendo que ao alterar uma DLL o processo é reiniciado pelo IIS.

Comment: existe como fazer a verificação de login sem utilizar session? algum componente interno?
hoje basicamente gravo na session a permissão para ele continuar logado

Comment: Tem sim, via cookie. É possível gravar informações de autorização no cookie de autenticação, criptografado é claro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para usar o servidor de sessão externo (out-of-process), você tem que:

- garantir que o servidor de sessão está ativo

  O servidor de sessão do ASP.NET é instalado como um serviço do Windows

  Na caixa de rodar aplicações do Windows (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) digite `services.msc` e localize o serviço `ASP.NET State Service`... é isso, ele tem que estar ativo.
- configurar o web.config

  ```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="StateServer"
        stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424"
        cookieless="false"
        timeout="20"/>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
  ```

Referência:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: ok, fui dar uma lida sobre o assunto, existe algum problema do tipo, depois de X dias o cara abre a página e continua com a session? eu configuro o tempo de expires?

Comment: Isso não seria um problema por assim dizer, e sim tu, configura ele ali no parâmetro `timeout="20"`.

Comment: existe algum efeito colateral dessa solução ? "State Server Mode" ? aumento de consumo de RAM ? lentidão? etc

Comment: O único efeito colateral que me lembro é que **todos os objetos armazenados na sessão deverão ser serializáveis**. Fora isso, é o mesmo que usar sessões in-process, só que agora, elas estarão armazenadas na memória de outro processo. A lentidão será a da latência de comunicação + serialização/desserialização, que em localhost deve ser próxima de zero.

Comment: Putz...vou ter que mudar toda a aplicação para serializar/deserializar as Sessions? :|

Comment: O que estiver gravando na sessão sim... infelizmente, o ASP.NET permite objetos vivos somente na sessão in-process. Para mim esse é um terrível erro cometido pelo ASP.NET, pois nenhuma alternativa vai permitir guardar objetos vivos.

Comment: Para minha sorte gravo apenas uma classe dentro da session (pelo menos foi o que vi) então só coloquei [Serializable] na classe e já começou a rodar..vou testar, mais..parece ser a solução.